# Allow gold language tag-badge holders to close too broad or otherwise off-topic questions, but are covered in the language tag wiki, single handedly

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, tag-wiki, tag-badges

#### The Problem

In highly active language tags we recurringly see questions from newcomers to the language (not necessarily beginners in programming), which are covered in basic tutorials, textbooks or even Wikipedia articles.

Stuff like

- What is C++?
- What's the best way to start Java programming?
- Can I run C# programs on any computer?
- Where can I find material about python programming?
- Who were the inventors of D?

I think those experienced with it will get the picture.

I cannot really speak for major programming language tag wikis other than [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ([C++ tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info)), but glancing over the ones for [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info), [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info), [**C**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info), or [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info), they seem to be of equal quality.
Most of those questions mentioned above are already answered there, and the OP has probably just missed clicking the link when  applying the tag.

#### Proposal

Gold badge holders for a language tag should be able to close such questions single-handedly, similar to duplicate hammering (i.e. peers can revert the question closure single-handedly as well, if they feel the reasoning is inappropriate).

Sometimes it is possible to close such questions with a canonical duplicate, but other times we meet such basic questions like the mentioned ones, which aren't really covered in a good duplicate.

For example, sometimes I close such questions as duplicates, but a link to the tag wiki would have been more appropriate. Here's a recent example:

[image: Screenshot of recently closed and deleted question.]

**Why gold badge holders? Isn't that a job for site moderators?**

The gold badge language tag holders are already trusted to be knowledgeable of the information available in the realm of their tags. Site moderators are explicitly not considered to moderate technical aspects of content as far as I know. Sometimes this coincides, but site moderators also need to choose a general close reason like *needs more focus*, *needs details or clarity*, or of course a duplicate question if appropriately available.

#### Benefits

While such questions are usually short lived, and are closed for a variety of reasons including as duplicates  of canonical or historically locked questions, the OP might have a better experience and get information if they are directly linked to the language tag wiki concerned.

Also this could help to reduce the noise occurring with such questions, which would likely just be downvoted, closevoted and deleted anyways.

---

From the comments and @Cody's answer here, I believe it's noteworthy to point out, that I am not talking about fast *"RTFM"* closures, or introducing *too basic* as a new close reason.

My proposal solely should apply to questions, ***which are actually answered*** in the language tag wiki, and there's **no appropriate duplicate** to select from the questions tagged [language-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-faq).

I believe instead of closing those questions with the regular close reasons which would apply, that this would give the OP and potentially other researchers a better source of information, than given with the links which appear in the regular close reason banners.
And of course I am only talking about questions, which are closeworthy and notably *off-topic* anyways.

Comment: The examples all seem as if other close reasons clearly apply to them. Is this intentional? If yes, does this not create problems that people are "encouraged" to ask bad questions, as they still get help for off-topic but basic questions?

Comment: *should be able to close such questions single handedly* --> I think the issue is in the "such". How to identify *such* question in order to allow you to close them? or does it mean that you are able to close *all* the question if you think they are basic ones (I doubt SO will agree with this ...)

Comment: @TemaniAfif One can simply read the tag wiki, same as with a duplicate. Also peers who disagree can reopen the question single handedly as well. Should I mention this in my request explicitely?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Of course I've chosen that example intentionally. I also don't see a problem with people get helped. Encouragement seems to be very low anyways.

Comment: seeing all the number of basic questions being answered, you will find a lot that will disagree with you :) allowing them to single-reopen the question will not help. By the way, many will also argue that some basic questions are still on-topic (unless there is a trivial duplicate for them). They deserve downvotes for *no research* but not close votes. This said, I am also with more power to be able to close question faster and still wating for many of my proposals to be considered for that ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif _"you will find a lot that will disagree with you :)"_ We once had a name for those unspoken ones ;-P

Comment: Closing trivial questions is one of the reasons people find StackOverflow elitist. I think it's  bad to close trivial questions as they may seem trivial to you but interesting to someone else. _Also this could help to reduce the noise occurring with such questions, which would likely just be downvoted, closevoted and deleted anyways._ ---> then let them be DCD'd. That's why we have moderation tools.

Comment: @10Rep _"I think it's bad to close trivial questions as they may seem trivial to you but interesting to someone else."_ Sure, but we don't need to answer these an umptenth gazillion times, if we have the answers already prominently at hand. That's one reason why we have a duplicate closure mechanism, and my only stance is that the same should be able for the language tag wiki. I'd be curious how you'd answer a question like _"What is Java?"_ better than done there already.

Comment: I woukd be happy to support the hammering of questions that are covered in the FAQ/wiki, eg the tera-dupe 'i++ + ++i' that appears daily:(

Comment: ..and 'scanf leaves a newline char in the buffer':(

Comment: ..and 'linkedListAdd(head, newItem)' does not update 'head'.

Comment: I mean, there is the SO rudeness, right there: 'I can't be bothered to read the FAQ, some naive drone must do it for me, else I'll scream and shout'.

Comment: I like this idea.

Comment: @Steve Also the same way as it's done with duplicate. _"Your question already has answers here: [c++ language tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) If you disagree, bla bla blah ..."_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it would be closed as a dupe with a dupe hammer. What are you suggesting? Are you suggesting that questions which don't have dupe targets but need to be closed can be closed by a dupe hammer?

Comment: Is there actually a Stack Overflow question *"What is C++?"*? (It is the first section in [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B/info).) Some broad questions about C++: *[What are the differences between C, C# and C++ in terms of real-world applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692225)*, *[What is a stream in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145357)*, *[What does '&' mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946191)*, *[What does :: mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833208)*

Comment: @adabsurdum _" should it be available for other users as a close-vote reason, too?"_ Thinking a bit longer about it, it could be as well a regular close reason. But the difference is the experience in that particular field (language tag), that's necessary to make this descision. As mentioned it's similar to dupe hammering.

Comment: @10Rep I am proposing that questions that don't have a well fitting dupe target, **but are answered in the tag wiki** can be closed for that reasoning.

Comment: Another very basic question (from 2013, 5 years after the launch of Stack Overflow), Java: *[What is an instance variable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686488)*

Comment: @Peter Is that covered in the Java tag wiki already?

Comment: My reaction to this, as a Python gold badge holder and 11-year user of the site, is approximately: "wait, *there are tag wikis*?".

Answer (score 13):

While I definitely think that question-closing powers need to be expanded in various ways, I am steadfastly against this specific proposal for the motivations cited in the question.

Stack Overflow doesn't do "RTFM" closures. **It doesn't matter one whit whether the question has been answered in the documentation, a textbook, basic tutorials, Wikipedia, the tag wiki, billboards, pop songs, the inside of your eyelids, or anywhere else.** All that matters is whether the question has previously been asked and answered on Stack Overflow. If it has, then the question is a duplicate. If it hasn't, and it's about programming, of sufficiently narrow scope that it can be answered here, and isn't primarily opinion-based, then it should be answered. It's as simple as that.

This is not about rudeness, or welcoming, or anything like that, so put away your conspiracy theories. This is just about being a Q&A site. Our fundamental mission is to provide high-quality, world-class answers to the long tail of programming questions, with the ultimate goal to become the best resource on the Internet for getting help. No question is "too basic". It's perfectly fine to ask, "How do I output a string in C++?", even though that's literally covered in every "Hello world" tutorial in existence. It doesn't count towards our knowledge base unless it's actually in our knowledge base.

That said, I think what you've actually identified a rather different problem, which should be solved in a different way. You cite several examples of problematic questions, so let's go through those:

> - What is C++?

That's not "too basic"; that's "too broad". There are only two answers that can be given to this. The first is a useless, one-sentence answer: "It is a programming language." The second is so long that it barely fits in a book. As such, this is not a valid question for Stack Overflow. It should be closed. Not for being "too basic", or because it's already covered elsewhere, but because it cannot be adequately covered here, in our Q&A format.

> - What's the best way to start Java programming?

This isn't "too basic", either. It's... well, it's too broad. It's also primarily opinion-based. There's no one "best way" to start anything. There are a variety of reasonable ways, and thus there could be as many answers provided to this question as there are users on this site. Again, this doesn't fit well into our Q&A format, so it needs to be closed, but not because it's already covered elsewhere.

> - Doing `var = ++var--;` gives strange results

Assuming, of course, that the body of the question contains a bit more details about the "strange results", this is a perfectly fine question for Stack Overflow. So fine, in fact, that it's been covered countless times and has several high-quality canonicals. If the site was just starting, it should be answered. Today, it should be closed as a duplicate. (Note: Not a duplicate of the manual. Not a duplicate of "Where can I find a C++ book?" Not as a duplicate of "What is undefined behavior?" It's not a duplicate of those broad, general questions. It's a specific, practical programming problem, and it should only be closed as a duplicate of a Q&A that actually answers the question.)

> - Can I run C# programs on any computer?

I can't decide if this one is "too broad" or perfectly acceptable. It would depend a lot on what clarification was provided in the body of the question. If the question was something like, "I have compiled my C# application to an executable, but I cannot run it on my friend's computer. What do I need to do in order to be able to run my C# application on another computer?", then that's a perfectly fine question for Stack Overflow. In light of that fineness, combined with how many years we've been doing this, it's also a duplicate many times over.

> - Where can I find material about python programming?

This isn't "too basic". We have perfectly good existing close reasons for this. It could be legitimately closed as being "too broad", but it could also be closed on the basis of its solicitation of recommendations for off-site resources.

> I'm a beginner completely in coding and i was wanting to make a script for my name in c++ I don't know the first place to start. I want the script to be on a cycle and to send strings like /sell and /upgrade. any and all help would be apricated [sic] thank you for putting the time in to read this.

That's not basic at all! It is, however, a very problematic question by Stack Overflow's standards. It lacks clarity, it lacks focus, and it cannot be reasonably answered in our Q&A format. It's highly closable, but it's definitely not a duplicate of "The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List", so you should absolutely not have closed it as a duplicate of that question.

> Sometimes it is possible to close such questions with a canonical duplicate, but other times we meet such basic questions like the mentioned ones, which aren't really covered in a good duplicate.

Yeah. If they're not covered in a good duplicate, and they don't fit any of the other close reasons, then they shouldn't be closed. Closing questions because you already know the answer (or know where to find the answer) is stupid and counter-productive.

---

So, what's the conclusion? Well, virtually all of these low-quality questions that you're talking about are blatantly inappropriate for Stack Overflow based on established guidelines. For all of the questions that should not be answered here, there is *at least* one correct close reason already available. That reason is not "Duplicate of the C++ Book List", nor do we have need to introduce a new "Already Covered By Other Stuff" close reason.

**What we need to do is expand the powers of gold tag-badge holders to be able to
single-handedly close questions as "unclear", "lacks a minimal reproducible example", "typo/not reproducible", "too broad", or "primarily opinion-based"** (*i.e.*, the existing standard official close reasons). As you said, these subject-matter experts are in the best position to determine whether a particular question falls into any of those categories. A C++ expert knows quite well whether "How do I display a simple message box?" is too broad to be answered (because there's no built-in GUI support in C++, so you'd have to pick a library, and the answer would be different on different platforms, etc.), whereas a Visual Basic programmer might say that the equivalent question in their language is quite straightforward and deserving of an answer. So, we should give C++ programmers the ability to make that determination for questions in their tag, and Visual Basic programmers the ability to make that determination for questions in their tag.

With closure privileges come reopening privileges, which means that gold tag badge holders would be able to immediately, single-handedly reopen these questions once they were edited into shape.

I cannot tell you how many times a PHP or R programmer has provided me with a link to a question that they believe needs to be closed for being too broad or for lacking a minimal reproducible example, yet when I look at the question, it looks totally fine to me. Why? Are these people just off their rocker, suggesting that questions get closed for inappropriate reasons? Well, sometimes. But usually not! Usually, it's my lack of subject-matter expertise that makes me unable to determine whether the snippet of code that is provided is a minimal reproducible example and/or whether the request is a sufficiently focused one in the context of their language/tools/ecosystem. I just don't know, so even though I have moderator privileges, I can't contribute to the closure of these questions. They need to be handled by subject-matter experts. Who better?

I really believe this provides a better solution to the low-quality questions that are irritating you, and a solution that is consistent with the fundamental mission of the site.

Comment: Yes, "needs more focus" is the new name of "too broad". They mean the same thing. The only thing that is missing from the revised description of "needs more focus" is an explanation of the fact that questions which contain a laundry list of questions are not suitable for this site. That's not at issue here, so the reasons can be considered identical.

Comment: @Cody I am not focusing that much at the _too basic_ reasoning, as it seems from your answer. Also it's not the RTFM aspect I had in mind. I rather meant that there are questions, which are in fact ***answered*** in the tag wiki already. At least answered in the way that you can find an up to date collection of links where one get get the information in question, if it's too long to fit well for SO's Q&A format.

Comment: If it can be answered in the tag wiki, then why shouldn't it just be answered in the answer box? I don't see any compelling reason whatsoever to allow a question to be closed as a duplicate of the tag wiki.

Comment: @CodyGray compelling reason would be that tag wiki is probably maintained better than some question lost in space, possibly hard to find unless it has 100 000 views. I would not mind being able to single handedly close other off topic or poor questions, but many times it has been said that could lead to abuse of power. Closing as duplicate of tag wiki, because it is answered there, at least has some grounds in already established practices.

Comment: @Cody I've edited my question a bit to make my point clearer. Note that I removed that prominent example regarding the UB of `var = ++var--;`.

Comment: You make a good argument. But for me the issue here is that this particular Question author is a subject matter expert in one (two) of the example Questions and argued to close that in a "RTFM"-closure. That just doesn't look very promising to me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ is it answered *by a question link* in the tag wiki, or by text? If by text, then it's probably unreasonable to expect OP to search for it in all of that text. If there's a link, then by all means *use the canonical duplicate for its intended purpose*. If a tag wiki contains text explicitly intended to address a common question in the tag, then *a canonical should be made from it*.